# How do I return specific value from this API

Tags: api, lua

Function/API Function: http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api/GetContainerItemInfo

There's a link top of this question. I can define a stack size of items with following:

`StackSize = GetContainerItemInfo(whichbag, whichslot);`

So basically I am asking how do I make the same thing with the item ID return? I have no clue at all how do lua "stores" the data in the way I've provided. The API documents says that it will return many data, but how do I define what I want to read from the following information: "texture, count, locked, quality, readable, lootable, link, isFiltered, hasNoValue, itemID"

Comment: Read the recommended and official documentations befor you do any further Lua programming. https://www.lua.org/docs.html

For this matter this is very important to undestand!
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua allows multiple return values and they act as variable arguments when returned by a function. So you may want to read on lua varargs if you need more tools to work with the return values.

On the documentation page you linked there is the function signature given in the following manner:

```
texture, count, locked, quality, readable, lootable, link, isFiltered, hasNoValue, itemID = GetContainerItemInfo(container, slot)
```

That is exactly the code that would define the following variables to have the corresponding values returned by the function: texture, count, locked, quality, readable, lootable, link, isFiltered, hasNoValue and itemID.

So you simply use that code and then use the variables you need that were just defined. In your case the `count` would be the stack size and the `itemID` would be the ID of the item.

Here is an example of how to print them after running the code above: `print(count, itemID)`

According to the documentation it seems as if the code you originally posted would not return the stacksize as you seem to assume, but the texture instead.

Comment: That's what I were thinking about, but I were wondering how it takes a stack size since it's not even in return list at all so I wasn't even sure.